# How to shift some values from one column to another in python / pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Some values are placed under wrong column in the dataset, which needs to be copied to some other column, so how to shift the values from one column to another. Images of the defected dataset and the expected output is given in the link below
Link to the images are given as 
Dataset problem
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0Gzw.jpg

Comment: Welcome to SO; this is a standard pandas question, and it has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `deep-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (please edit to remove them).

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, i have removed extra tags and edit the content also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that pandas considers ; as a column separator. You should modify your data set.

If you can't do this here an example of what you're trying to do :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Genres' : ['Art & Design', 'Art & Design'],'Last updated' : ['January 16', 'Pretend Play'], 'Current Ver' : ['1.0.0', 'January 15',
                                                            ], 'Unnamed: 14': [np.nan ,'4.03 and up']})

         Genres  Last updated Current Ver  Unnamed: 14
0  Art & Design    January 16       1.0.0          NaN
1  Art & Design  Pretend Play  January 15  4.03 and up

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Unnamed: 14'] is not np.nan:
        print(row['Last updated'])
        df.loc[index, 'Genres'] += ';' + row['Last updated']
        df.loc[index, 'Last updated'] = row['Current Ver']
        df.loc[index, 'Current Ver'] = row['Unnamed: 14']
```

Output :

```
                      Genres Last updated  Current Ver  Unnamed: 14
0               Art & Design   January 16        1.0.0          NaN
1  Art & Design;Pretend Play   January 15  4.03 and up  4.03 and up
```